# javascript build programatically a reference to recursive object keys

Tags: javascript

supposing this string:

```
var string = 'abcd';

//I split the string by characters
var keys = string.split(''); // that return ['a','b','c','d'];
```

now I have an object like this:

```
var object = {
    a:{
        b:{
            c:{
                d:{

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

how to built programatically some like:
`object['a']['b']['c']['d']`;
from the `keys` array;

Comment: Do you want to *build* an object, or *access* the existing object?

Comment: access the existing obj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `reduce`, passing along the current nested object as the accumulator (with the base object as the initial value):

```js
var object = {
    a:{
        b:{
            c:{
                d:{
                  foo: 'bar'
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
var string = 'abcd';
var keys = string.split('');
console.log(
  keys.reduce((a, key) => a[key], object)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

i think you can reverse the array and keep set the parent-child object

```
var string = 'abcd';
var arr = string.split('');

var result = arr.reverse().reduce(function(obj, key) {
  var o = {};
  o[key] = obj;
  return o;
}, {});
```

Comment: This not work. this make a new object. I need to access the existing `object`